# How to generate random number each time

Tags: javascript, variables, math, random, increment

Does anyone know how do i generate a new random number so i can store them into different variables? (into temp1 and temp2) I want the program to rerun the "randomnumber" function each time for each new variable so i can store the new random value into them.

```js
<HTML>
<!Foundation Page for building our Javascript programs>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>The Foundation Page </TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "JavaScript">
function main()
{
 totalscore()
 leaderboard()
}


function randomnumber()
{
 var randomnumber;
 randomnumber = Math.random()*3;
 return(Math.floor(randomnumber+0.2));
}
function totalscore() 
{
 var n;
 var p;
 var total;
 var temp1; 
 var temp2;
 var score; 

 
 score = 0;
 total=0
 
 for (n=0; n<10; n=n+1)
 {
  number = randomnumber();
  if (number == 0)
   {
    score =score+0;
   }
  else if (number == 2)
   {
    score =score+2;
   }
  else if (number == 3)
   {
    score =score+3;
   }
 total=total+score;
 }
temp1= total
temp2= total 
document.write(total)
document.write(total)

 
}

</SCRIPT>
<HEAD>
<BODY>
<BODY BGCOLOUR = "WHITE">
<H2>The Foundation Page </H2>
<HR>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "Javascript"> main() </SCRIPT>
<INPUT NAME = "dobutton" TYPE = "button" value = "Start game" on Click = "game()"> 
<INPUT NAME = "dobutton" TYPE = "button" value = "Leaderboard" on Click = "leader()">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem, why can't you call randomnumber function more than one time ?(one time for every variable you want to store the random in)

Comment: Sorry about the bad explanation, i wanted to generate new random value and store them into temp1 and temp2. But, the random number generator is printing 2 of the same number value (e.g. 32, 32)

Comment: put `score = 0; ... for(...)...` into an inner function an call it before each assignment.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding on what your saying.

Comment: So after the script runs, you want `temp1` and `temp2` to have different random numbers?  Then why do you say `temp1= total; temp2= total;`?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking either. Also, you know your randomnumber() function produces values 0,1,2, and 3, but with frequencies 8,10,10, and 2.

Comment: please Ruben explain your question

Comment: I thought that the "total" will generate a new random value for "temp1/2" each time i call "total" but it isn't a case, i was wondering how do i make the random number generator to create a new value when i call "total"

Comment: `total` is a variable.  You don't call it, you just assign numbers to it and read from it.  `randomnumber()` is a function that returns a new value each time you call it.

Comment: What you need is a programming tutorial. Mixing up variables and functions is some pretty basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you are asking and I'll post working code below as well as an explanation of why you are getting the same random number.

1. You have a for loop is generating the score and and returning a value that you are storing into total. The problem is you are assigning that number to both temp1 AND temp 2, so they are now the same number, then you are writing both numbers to the page. What you need to do is have 2 different calculations. the below code will fix it and give you 2 different numbers for you totals...

   ```
   function totalscore() 
   {
       var total1 = 0;
       var total2 = 0;

       for (var n=0; n<10; n++)
       {
           total1 = total1 + randomnumber();
           total2 = total2 + randomnumber();
       }
       document.write(total1);
       document.write(total2);

   }
   ```
2. Now I was a little confused at your code because the score is compounding on itself every time it recalculates in the for loop. (ie if the first 5 scores were 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, then the total score would be 24, and not the expected 9. If that was intentional, the put in this code instead.

   ```
   function totalscore() 
   {
       var total1 = 0;
       var total2 = 0;
       var score1 = 0; 
       var score2 = 0; 

       for (var n=0; n<10; n++)
       {
           score1 = score1 + randomnumber();
           total1 = total1 + score1;
           score2 = score2 + randomnumber();
           total2 = total2 + score2;
       }

       document.write(total1);
       document.write(total2);
   }
   ```

Good luck with your project and learning coding!

Answer (score 0):

Issues I am noticing

1. No semicolons behind most statements
2. You are returning Math.floor on randomnumber + 0.2, which makes + 0.2 do nothing.
3. You are calling onclick='game()' on button click, but there is no game(), but maybe that's in code we can't see.
4. You are setting both temp1 and temp2 = total, and using document.write on total twice

Now, the question is how to generate a random number. You are doing that correctly, although you could simplify it and use `Math.floor(Math.random()*3)` or `return Math.floor(Math.random()*3)`. Of course, you can switch out 3 and replace it now with whatever cap you wish.